# Is it possible to do a find and replace on a value found between two strings only?

Tags: excel

I have text that looks like this which is stored in a single cell in Excel:

```
AAA https://somesite.com/?param1=value1 BBB CCC https://somesite.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2 DDD
```

Is it possible to find/replace the param1=value1 string found between strings AAA and BBB only? Like using a pattern match or regex? Or use a REPLACE/SUBSTITUTE function to accomplish this?

For context, I am trying to modify a rather long ad tag that has a set of noscript tags which only evaluate when JavaScript is turned off in the browser.

I want to modify a portion of the impression tracking URL that is found between the noscript tags only. It will be something like search for param1=value1 and replace it with param1=value1&param2=value2. But param1=value1 also exists in the script tag and I don't want to replace this value because the script portion of the tag URL has the param2=value2 already included.

The ad server was essentially built to modify script portions of the tags, not noscript portions of the tags. I want to do a conditional find/replace in values found between the noscript tags only. But not sure how.

Thanks,

Comment: If you use find() and search for "?param1*" then it will return the first one it finds. Do it twice for the second…

Comment: Can I search for something like "<noscript> * ?param1 * </noscript>" using * as wildcard?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?